# Convert a csv dataset into HDF5 for nilmtk

Tags: python, hdf5

i am recently looking into [nilmtk](https://github.com/nilmtk/nilmtk) project. I was able to install its toolkits and run its example. But I get stuck when I try to convert my dataset into [Dataset metadata](http://nilm-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataset_metadata.html#meterdevice) in HDF5 as [required](https://github.com/nilmtk/nilmtk/blob/master/docs/manual/user_guide/data.ipynb).

I am not familiar how to deal with HDF5 format but found out it can import anything and requires attributes. I suppose I have to create attributes for each item in the HDF5 tree (node, leaf, folder).

But the most part struggling me is when the redd.h5 example dataset format:

```
import pandas as pd 
import h5py
redd = pd.HDFStore('redd.h5')
redd.keys()
redd['/building6/elec/meter1']


Out[92]: 
physical_quantity              power
type                        apparent
2011-05-21 15:39:19-04:00  47.000000
2011-05-21 15:39:21-04:00  46.919998
2011-05-21 15:39:22-04:00  47.020000
...
```

"type" is under "physical_quantity" and "apparent" is under "power" as mentioned in MeterDevice in [document](http://nilm-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dataset_metadata.html#meterdevice)
How can I create this type of (two rows label) table in python?

My data for numbers of appliance are already ready to be extract from Fluke Analyze. At this point, I just want to run my own dataset with nilmtk toolkit. Hope someone can guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two-row labels you're seeing are a [Pandas MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).  In this particular case, the DataFrame's columns are a MultiIndex, which basically means there is a hierarchy of column labels with multiple levels.

You can make your own DataFrame with multi-level column labels like this:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [('physical_quantity', 'type'), ('power', 'apparent')])
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=cols)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I wonder if this hierarchy of column labels is independent to the HDF5 format. just wonder...
one quick question. how to set index to the first column ('physical_quantity', 'type')?
preprocess.set_index('physical_quantity', 'type') seem not working.

Comment: @Simon: I'm not sure, to be honest.  You might want to open a new question if you need help with that.  Or take the DataFrame you have, and inspect its `index` and `columns` to figure it out.